# nodejs download the newly created file

Tags: node.js, express

To process a request, first determine whether the file exits. If it does not exist, create the file first, and finally return the file, but when the file does not exist, the return file is empty...

```
fn: async ctx => {
    let filePath = path.join(__dirname,'..',fileDir,fileName)
    if (!fs.existsSync(filePath)){
        if(!fs.existsSync(fileDir)){
            fs.mkdirSync(fileDir)
        }
        command = batCommand + ctx.req.query.git_name + " " + ctx.req.query.git_email
        await fs.writeFile(filePath,command,err =>{
            if (err){
                return err
            }
            return "ok"
        })
    }
    ctx.res.download(filePath)
    return 1
}
```

I am aware of the return of the callback function.

Comment: You can't `await` a callback-based function.

Comment: I thought it was returned before the end of writeFile execution,so I added await

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this code snippet solves your problem,

```
fn: ctx => {
  let filePath = path.join(__dirname, '..', fileDir, fileName)
  try {
    if (!fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
      if (!fs.existsSync(fileDir)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(fileDir)
      }
      command = batCommand + ctx.req.query.git_name + " " + ctx.req.query.git_email
      fs.writeFileSync(filePath, command);
    }
    return ctx.res.download(filePath)
  } catch{
    return err
  }
}
```